# How can I convert a Georgian CPL to an EASA frozen ATPL?

Tags: easa-regulations, cpl

I am interested in how I can convert my CPL issued by Georgia to a frozen ATPL? Georgia is not a member of EASA.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I edited your question a little, I hope it's correct but you can always edit it again yourself if I made a mistake.

Comment: Does your Georgian license [comply with ICAO standards](http://www.icao.int/safety/airnavigation/Pages/peltrgFAQ.aspx#anchor09)?